# CSS with .htc behavior file and virtual subdomain

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css3pie, html-components

I'm interested in using [border-radius.htc](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) or [css3pie.htc](http://css3pie.com/) in my stylesheet to enable newer CSS3 abilities in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Unfortunately, MSIE requires that the .htc behavior file must be in the same domain as the HTML page which uses it.

How would one go about using the .htc file when the subdomain is virtual (created by WordPress MultiSite, in my instance)?

Comment: Actually, WordPress will probably also be the solution to this problem. I believe that using a relative URL in the stylesheet (to the theme's files) will simulate the same domain requirement. Alas, an untested afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use csspie.js: http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Comment: Indeed! Certainly more than a few disadvantages, though (also listed on that page).